# Squid and Varnish only allow one request to same at a time

Tags: squid, varnish

I am comparing Squid, Varnish and Ngix. Does Squid and Varnish have this Ngix feature?

> When proxy_cache_lock is enabled, only one request at a time will be allowed to populate a new cache element identified according to the proxy_cache_key directive by passing a request to a proxied server. Other requests of the same cache element will either wait for a response to appear in the cache, or the cache lock for this element to be released ...

Basically, I want to prevent Squid from doing concurrent request to the same cachable resource. Example: When 10 clients request the same uncached URI concurrently, Squid will only do one request then return the same result to the other 9 clients.

Answer (score 2):

Varnish does this.  See [here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html).

Answer (score 2):

In squid this feature is called "collapsed_forwarding," it is a feature present in the 2.7 release of Squid which has recently been ported to squid 3.5 which is still in the early stages of development.